# Shell: conditional appending or copying of CSVs with header

Tags: bash, shell, csv

Target:

1. Copy a CSV with header from one directory to another.
2. If the CSV already exists in the target directory append it to the existing CSV instead.
3. Do not append the CSV header.

What is the fastet bash/shell solution with the fewest lines?

Simple solution:

```
FILE=file.csv
TARGET=path/to/file.csv
if [ -f "$TARGET" ]; then
    sed 1d $FILE >> $TARGET
else 
    cp $FILE $TARGET
fi
```

Comment: fastest, fewest lines or fewest instructions ? the first one generally has nothing to do with the others, and fewest line is much easier to achieve then fewest instruction but hardly helps with anything. Anyway I think you won't get much faster or cleaner than your current solution

Comment: @gustavz : You can use `tail` to copy the file without the header.

Comment: And any script can be one-lined by replacing linefeeds with `;`, so `FILE=file.csv; TARGET=path/to/file/csv; if [ -f "$TARGET" ]; then sed 1d "$FILE" >> "$TARGET"; else cp "$FILE" "$TARGET"; fi` works just fine if you want a one-liner.

Comment: Test your implementations in a loop then use `time`. Then see how marginal performance differences are with a shell script, where the right algorithm most always offer the optimal performances and any other syntactic fanciness is a bug nest. Example `time sh -c 'i=10000;while i=$((i-1)); [ $i -gt 0 ]; do tail -n+2 a; done >/dev/null 2>&1'`

Comment: `tail -n+2` is marginally faster than `sed 1d`. But I can't believe it matters for your shell script. If performance is a real concern, then shell is probably not a wise language choice for the task. I now think about closing your question as needing more focus. Performance and shell is an oxymoron. If you ask for performance on a shell script, then you have many more questions to answer and code design choices to review than can fit here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this -

```
{ [[ -s "$target" ]] && sed 1d "$file" || cat "$file"; } >> "$target"
```

You'd need to switch the test to `-s` since the `>> $target` creates the file before the test happens if it wasn't there...

But don't.

Better to leave it as you have it. Fewer lines isn't better.
In fact, add comments.

Clarity > Brevity.

---

[Lea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7939871/l%c3%a9a-gris)'s awesome version, totally POSIX compliant:

```
[ -f "$target" ]; tail -n+$(($? ? 1 : 2)) "$file" >>"$target"
```

That's a thing of beauty, lol >;o]

Comment: I tried the same but failed ;)

Comment: Worked for me. Again, I recommend you NOT use this, but now I'd like to know why it failed, lol. Did you forget the semicolon after `cat $FILE;`? That one is required if you're going to put the `} >> $TARGET` on the same line. (Also, don't use uppercase vars...)

Comment: No no i tried to find a similar solution but was not able to figure it out like you.

Comment: Try this instead: `[ -f "$target" ] && set -- tail -n+2 || set -- cat; "$@" "$file"  >>"$target"` or alternatively `[ -f "$target" ]; tail -n+$((2-$?)) "$file" >>"$target" `, or more semantically correct: `[ -f "$target" ]; tail -n+$(($??2:1)) "$file" >>"$target"`

Comment: Cannot correct my comment anymore but the ternary arithmetic is `tail -n+$(($??1:2))` because `$? = 0` which turns to `false` in shell arithmetic when file exists.

Comment: @Lea, that's so pretty I had to include it in my answer and credit the author. :)

Comment: Use single square brackets for the test `[ -f "$target" ]` and the whole stuff is POSIX compliant; rather than using the Bash's double square brackets `[[ test ]]` syntax.

Comment: That's true - I always use the `bash` doubles because we have no non-bash systems, but in any env where there are or could be variance, it's important. Will edit.